# Undefined reference error in NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, undefined-reference

I am trying to compile [unrar](http://www.rarlab.com/rar/unrarsrc-5.3.6.tar.gz) for `Android` but getting some `undefined reference error`. I am stuck here for couple of days but can't find the exact problem. I tried to write `Android.mk` from existing `makefile`.

## Error

```
jni/unrar/rar.cpp:104: error: undefined reference to 'CommandData::ParseCommandLine(bool, int, char**)'
jni/unrar/rar.cpp:107: error: undefined reference to 'CommandData::ReadConfig()'
jni/unrar/rar.cpp:108: error: undefined reference to 'CommandData::ParseEnvVar()'
jni/unrar/rar.cpp:110: error: undefined reference to 'CommandData::ParseCommandLine(bool, int, char**)'
```

## Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
UNRAR_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/unrar
LOCAL_MODULE    := unrar-jni

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_unrar_jni.cpp unrar/rar.cpp unrar/strlist.cpp unrar/strfn.cpp unrar/pathfn.cpp unrar/smallfn.cpp unrar/global.cpp unrar/file.cpp unrar/filefn.cpp unrar/filcreat.cpp \
    unrar/archive.cpp unrar/arcread.cpp unrar/unicode.cpp unrar/system.cpp unrar/isnt.cpp unrar/crypt.cpp unrar/crc.cpp unrar/rawread.cpp unrar/encname.cpp \
    unrar/resource.cpp unrar/match.cpp unrar/timefn.cpp unrar/rdwrfn.cpp unrar/consio.cpp unrar/options.cpp unrar/errhnd.cpp unrar/rarvm.cpp unrar/secpassword.cpp \
    unrar/rijndael.cpp unrar/getbits.cpp unrar/sha1.cpp unrar/sha256.cpp unrar/blake2s.cpp unrar/hash.cpp unrar/extinfo.cpp unrar/extract.cpp unrar/volume.cpp \
    unrar/list.cpp unrar/find.cpp unrar/unpack.cpp unrar/headers.cpp unrar/threadpool.cpp unrar/rs16.cpp unrar/cmddata.cpp unrar/ui.cpp \
    unrar/filestr.cpp unrar/recvol.cpp unrar/rs.cpp unrar/scantree.cpp unrar/qopen.cpp 

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -O2
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -fexceptions -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

`CommandData` declares in `cmddata.hpp` and implemented in `cmddata.cpp` file. `rar.hpp` also includes `cmddata.hpp` But why it's complaining that functions are undefined.

Comment: Something is wrong with your link. ui.cpp does not exist in the tar file.

Comment: @AlexCohn I have fixed link.

Comment: The source code you found is not complete, and does not carry official claims to compile, especially under Android. The file **GUI/arajni.hpp** is simply missing from the tar. The function **JniCharToWide()** is never declared, and so on. I could create libunrar-jni.so only after manually editing **rar.hpp** file: I added `#undef _ANDROID` before the `#ifdef _ANDROID` on line 89. The command line: `ndk-build APP_STL=c++_static`

Comment: @AlexCohn Yes, I manually comment all #ifdef _ANDROID code section. They used jni callback but I think it's not required for now.

Comment: I found that all _ANDROID results in bad build. Try the single change as I suggested above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94905/discussion-between-alex-cohn-and-shantanu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code you found is not complete, and does not carry official claims to compile, especially under Android. But the following steps can get you started:

1. open new directory, open command line to that directory.
2. `mkdir jni`
3. put the Android.mk exactly as you have in your question to **jni** directory
4. untar unrarsrc-5.3.6.tar.gz to **jni/unrar**
5. add one line #88 in **jni/unrar/rar.hpp**: `#undef _ANDROID`
6. create empty file **jni/com_unrar_jni.cpp**
7. run `ndk-build APP_CFLAGS="-Dgetpass\(a\)=a" APP_STL=stlport_static` *c++_static may work, too*)